# Сортировка слиянием больших файлов. Как сделать?

Tags: java, сортировка

Есть некая задача - нужно написать программу сортировки слиянием нескольких файлов(например есть 2 файла - первый файл содержит 2,3,5,7 , второй файл 1,2,4,6 - на выходе должен быть файл с содержимым 1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7). Трудность состоит в том что нужно реализовать эту задачу без использования библиотек и чтобы алгоритм был устойчив к большим файлам, не помещающимся в оперативную память. Подскажите с чего начать, больше волнует вторая часть вопроса с большими файлами...

Comment: А файлы уже отсортированы?

Comment: да, файлы  отсортированы

Comment: 1) читаем по числу из каждого файла 2) наименьшее число пишем в выходной файл 3) Читаем след число из того файла, где было наименьшее число на шаге 2 4) goto шаг 1

Comment: Обычная сортировка слиянием, но с использованием ридеров и врайтера для файлов.

Comment: при таком подходе условие "большие файлы не помещающиеся в оперативную память" точно будет выполняться?

Comment: @tym32167, но-но, не говорите `goto`, студенты выполняют всё буквально=D